# Increase the name of a variable in Jquery

Tags: jquery, variables

I was searching the site for hours (literally) but i couldn't find any solution, so here I'm creating a new post.

First of all, I'm new with jQuery, maybe this has a simple solution.

I have this problem: I'm practicing with jQuery and I'm making a copy of the comment system of facebook (kinda). I made the like counter creating a variable, and when click on the button, the variable increase the value. Until here it works fine.

Each comment has its own like counter, then I guess every variable in a post should have a different name. I need that the name of the variable change automatically, for now i cannot do it so when a click the button, it affects the likes in all comments. I mean, when I click in one button, all the likes increase (and thats why they share the same variable).

I need that when a comment is created, it also creates a new variable (for example, comment 1 creates var like1). Here is the code:

When the comment is ready, it creates the answer with the like button:

```
$(this).closest('.box').append('<div class="box2">' + comentario2  + '<br/>' + ' +'<input type="submit" value="me gusta" class="like">' + '<div class="counter">' + '</div>'+ '</div>');
```

When click on like, the var increases, and affects all the like counters.

```
var contador= 0; $(document).on( 'click', '.like', function() {
contador++;
$('.counter').html(contador);});
```

Thank in advance for any help!

Comment: Try this. I've created an example which should help you achieve what you need : http://jsfiddle.net/VUZhL/2187/ .